# Setting FrontEnd`$ControlActive in EventHandler

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

Is it possible to emulate the behaviour of `ControlActive[]` for an ordinary
`Control[]` when implemented by an `EventHandler[]`?

For example, the following will display `False` unless the slider is being manipulated.

```
In[1]:= Slider[Dynamic[u]]
In[2]:= Dynamic[u; ControlActive[]]
```

`ControlActive[]`, via `$ControlActiveSetting` asks the front-end for the value of `` FrontEnd`$ControlActive ``.  `Out[3]` updates whenever any control is active.

```
In[3]:= Dynamic[FrontEnd`$ControlActive]
```

I'd like to be able to do something like the following.  However, it has no effect (on either `Out[4]` or `Out[3]`):

```
In[4]:= EventHandler[
 Graphics@Dynamic[ u; ControlActive[Circle[], Disk[]] ],
 {
  "MouseDown" :> (u += 0.1; MathLink`CallFrontEndHeld@FrontEnd`SetValue@FEPrivate`Set[FrontEnd`$ControlActive, True]),
  "MouseUp" :> (u -= 0.1; MathLink`CallFrontEndHeld@FrontEnd`SetValue@FEPrivate`Set[FrontEnd`$ControlActive, False])
  }
 ]
```

By a quirk of implementation, `$ControlActiveSetting` uses `CallFrontEnd[]` rather than the Held form, so it is possible to do the following, which shows the desired effect, but has the side-effect of breaking normal uses of `ControlActive[]` -- clicking the graphic will cause `Out[6]` and `Out[2]` to update, and manipulating the slider of `Out[1]` will have no effect on `Out[2]` until the non-front-end `` FrontEnd`$ControlActive `` is cleared.

```
In[5]:= FrontEnd`$ControlActive = False;
In[6]:= EventHandler[
 Graphics[ Dynamic@ControlActive[Circle[], Disk[]] ],
 {
  "MouseDown" :> (FrontEnd`$ControlActive = True),
  "MouseUp" :> (FrontEnd`$ControlActive = False)
  }
 ]
```

The obvious work-around is to use a different variable and a wrapper around `ControlActive[]` that checks both.  I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Assuming a solution, can one further restrict/scope the setting of `` FrontEnd`$ControlActive ``
to affect only a particular dynamic variable?  Ie, assuming some `Dynamic[v]`, the event handler would only trigger updates of `Dynamic[v; ControlActive[]]` and not, for instance, `Out[2]` above.

**Edit:** Added missing dynamic trigger to `In[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

`` FrontEnd`$ControlActive `` is read-only.